# Problema al realizar segues en mi app con Firebase

Tags: firebase, ios, swift, google-signin, firebase-auth

Estoy realizando un app en la cual guardo los usuarios que se autentican en el Firebase Realtime Database. Cada usuario es guardado en el Database con un atributo booleano llamado 'isAdmin', el cual permite realizar distintos segues según su valor. El problema que estoy teniendo es que, cuando el usuario tiene el 'isAdmin' = false, la app funciona correctamente y realiza el segue 'inicio', pero cuando el usuario tiene el  'isAdmin' = true:

- 1- realiza el segue 'inicio2' (lo cual es correcto y debería llegar a
  eso),
- 2- cambia el valor de 'isAdmin' a 'false'
- 3- realiza el segue    'inicio', por encima del paso 1.

Necesito que no me realice el segundo paso, es decir, que el valor de 'isAdmin' no cambie a 'false'.

Esto ocurre al presionar el boton relacionado al IBAction 'iniciarSesionGoogle'

Dejo código aquí debajo:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import GoogleSignIn

class InicioSesion: UIViewController, GIDSignInDelegate, GIDSignInUIDelegate{

    //OUTLETS
    @IBOutlet weak var correo: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var botonIniciarSesion: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var botonRegistrarme: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var botonFacebook: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var botonGoogle: UIButton!

    //VARIABLES
    var ref: DatabaseReference!
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?

    //FUNCIONES
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.uiDelegate = self

        ref = Database.database().reference()

        correo.text = ""
        password.text = ""

        botonIniciarSesion.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        botonRegistrarme.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        botonFacebook.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        botonGoogle.layer.cornerRadius = 10

        //Se agrega tap para ocultar teclado
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(("ocultarTeclado")))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print("No estamos logueados")
            } else {
                guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
                print(userID)

                self.ref.child("users").child(userID).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
                    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                    let admin = value?["isAdmin"] as? Bool

                    //print(admin!)

                    if admin == false {
                        print("Si estamos logueados")
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "inicio", sender: self)
                        print("Entró 1")
                        print("aca 1")
                    } else {
                        print("Si estamos logueados")
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "inicio2", sender: self)
                        print("Entró 2")
                        print("aca 1")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle!)

    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        Auth.auth().removeStateDidChangeListener(handle!)
    }


    //MARK: INICIO SESION GOOGLE
    @IBAction func iniciarSesionGoogle(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //print("google")
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Error Google Sign In", error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }

            let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
                if user != nil {

                    self.guardarUsuarioGoogle()  //ARREGLAR: NO ESTA GUARDANDO EN EL DATABASE

                    guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
                    print(userID)

                    //Obtengo usuario del Database
                    //Toma el valor de 'isAdmin' para realizar el segue correspondiente
                    self.ref.child("users").child(userID).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

                        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                        let admin = value?["isAdmin"] as? Bool

                        //print(admin!)

                        if admin == false {
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "inicio", sender: self)
                            print("Entró 1")
                            print("aca 4")
                        } else if admin == true {
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "inicio2", sender: self)
                            print("Entró 2")
                            print("aca 4")
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn?, present viewController: UIViewController?) {
        // Mostrar ventana de autenticación OAuth2
        if let aController = viewController {
            present(aController, animated: true) {() -> Void in }
        }
    }

    // Despues de la autenticacion de Google OAuth2
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn?, dismiss viewController: UIViewController?) {
        // Cerrar ventana de autenticación OAuth2
        dismiss(animated: true) {() -> Void in }
    }

    func guardarUsuarioGoogle() {
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        self.ref.child("users").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            for _ in snapshot.children.allObjects {
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let idUsuario = value?["idUser"] as? String

                if idUsuario != userID {
                    guard let id = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
                    guard let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email else { return }
                    let isAdmin = false
                    let metodo = "google"
                    let campos = ["correo": email, "idUser": id, "isAdmin": isAdmin, "metodoAcceso": metodo] as [String : Any]
                    self.ref.child("users").child(id).setValue(campos)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cada vez que ejecutas `func sign(...)` tenes un metodo llamado `guardarUsuarioGoogle()`, si revisamos el metodo

```
func guardarUsuarioGoogle() {
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid

        self.ref.child("users").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            for _ in snapshot.children.allObjects {
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let idUsuario = value?["idUser"] as? String

                if idUsuario != userID {
                    guard let id = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
                    guard let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email else { return }
                    let isAdmin = false // Aca es donde se te esta cambiando en cada login
                    let metodo = "google"
                    let campos = ["correo": email, "idUser": id, "isAdmin": isAdmin, "metodoAcceso": metodo] as [String : Any]
                    self.ref.child("users").child(id).setValue(campos)
                }
            }
        }
```

Tenes que  `let isAdmin = false` , aca es donde se esta haciendo la asignación, para corregir eso, lo que podes hacer es que cada vez que inicie sesion se fije si `isAdmin` existe ya en ese usuario, si ya existe no lo modificas, si no existe lo seteas.

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Error Google Sign In", error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }

            let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)

            Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
                if user != nil {

                    guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
                    print(userID)

                    //Obtengo usuario del Database
                    //Toma el valor de 'isAdmin' para realizar el segue correspondiente
                    self.ref.child("users").child(userID).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
                        if snapshot.hasChild("isAdmin"){

                        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                        let admin = value?["isAdmin"] as? Bool

                        //print(admin!)

                        if admin == false {
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "inicio", sender: self)
                            print("Entró 1")
                            print("aca 4")
                        } else if admin == true {
                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "inicio2", sender: self)
                            print("Entró 2")
                            print("aca 4")
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
         // No existe el valor de isAdmin, podemos setearlo 
          self.guardarUsuarioGoogle()
       }
    }
```

Nunca use swift, pero mas o menos asi debe ser el if que tenes que usar